# React Native или React PWA

Tags: react-native, pwa

Необходимо простое кросплатформенное приложение.
Какие есть плюсы и минусы React Native и PWA?

Визуально должно выглядеть похожим на стандартные приложения, т.е навигация меню и тд. Понимаю, что можно добиться и в PWA того-же.

Пока склоняюсь к PWA, но вероятно могут взоникнуть проблемы при навигации или работы с меню. Возможно будет расширение функционала, могут понадобятся какие-то специфичные вещи вроде построения графиков или работы с push нотификацией.

Comment: В итоге у PWA для меня есть один довольно существенный минус на текущий момент. Когда необходимо использовать push api, то apple как всегда отстает от всех. Даже microsoft со своими браузерами поддерживает. А с учетом того, что push уведомления очень нужны в мобильных приложениях, то приходится костылить свои инструменты при работе с apple. Да и все косяки появляющиеся при разработке PWA упираются в основном в apple и их safari

Answer (score 0):

В случае с React Native скорее всего подразумевается, что будет использоваться [Expo](https://expo.io/). На моем опыте произошел конфуз: в самый удобный момент облако обновили и мой проект перестал собираться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому, в случае когда разработчик у проекта один, я бы рекомендовал PWA с применением прошлой ветки библиотеки [MaterialUi](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/material-ui-global-modules), так как для нее есть типизация TypeScript для umd дистрибутива.